# Is there diference in this two JSON objects, look like there is no, but

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

When I send data (values and dates) from function (hard coded), everything is ok, json file is populated, and I see the chart, but when I send data from database, there is no chart but I see that json file is also populeted.

Here is code:

```
public class YearlyStat
{
    public string year { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Statistics(int? id)
{
    //var result = db.pricepoints.Where(r => r.commodityID.Equals(id));
    var items = from item in db.pricepoints
                where (item.commodityID == id)
                select item;

    var stats = new List<YearlyStat>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        stats.Add(new YearlyStat
        {
            year = item.date_of_price.ToShortDateString(),
            value = item.value
        });

    }
    //but this works
    //string s = "2.2.2002";
    //double v = 20.20;
    //stats.Add(new YearlyStat { year = s, value = v });
    //or
    //stats.Add(new YearlyStat { year = "2.2.2002", value = 20.20 });

    return Json(stats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Types are string and double in both cases.

Comment: Did you look at the response to see what is different?

Comment: It' works now, this code is corect, problem is in my javascript where i did not send id parametar to this function. Tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

I get it :D

Problem is in my JavaScript, i didn't send 'id' parametar to Statistics function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('@Url.Action("Statistics")', function(result){
    new Morris.Line({
        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
        element: 'myfirstchart',
        // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
        // the chart.
        data: 
          result
        ,
        // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
        xkey: 'year',
        // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
        ykeys: ['value'],
        // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
        // chart.
        labels: ['Value','Date']
    });
});
```

It works when i put:

```
@Url.Action("Statistics", new { id = ViewBag.commodityID })
```

Now im happy man :D